# AttributeError: type object 'Product' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, django-models

I am pretty new in Python / Django so please bear .. I am unable to run any commands and the terminal produces the same error every time.

My Model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_price = models.IntegerField()
    item_image = models.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['item_name']
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Product

class Product(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.register(Product)(admin.ModelAdmin)
```

Traceback :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/yogesh/ShoppingSite/portal/admin.py", line 11, in <module>
    admin.register(Product)(admin.ModelAdmin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/decorators.py", line 25, in _model_admin_wrapper
    admin_site.register(models, admin_class=admin_class)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 85, in register
    if model._meta.abstract:
AttributeError: type object 'Product has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems from the traceback that the problem is coming from your `admin.py`. If you are using the [`admin.register`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator) decorator make sure you are using it right:

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Or, you can use the `admin.site.register` function:

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```